# Replacing alt and title with filter for each image in post (WordPress)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, alt, add-filter

I have updated hundreds of images in WordPress with the proper alt and title information in the media library and now I need to get the page to render the correct information without having to update each page individually.

It seems like using `add_filter` or something similar will do what I need, but I'm not sure whether I need to figure out a regular expression or if I can just use `the_content`.

I have put together a way to get all attached images and display the correct alt and title tags, but I only know how to add the images to the beginning or end of `the_content`. I need it to replace each corresponding image that is already there. Is there a better way to do this? Here is a function to put the new image content into an array:

```
function replaceimages_get_images($content) {
    global $post;
    $images = array();
    $x = 0;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
            $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
            $alt = apply_filters( 'alt', get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ));
            $images[$x] = '<img src="'.$src[0].'" title="'.$title.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
            $x++;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'replaceimages_get_images' );
```

I need to now, in pseudocode, do the following:

```
for each image in $content {
    match src to image in array;
    replace entire image with image from array;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach will consume resources at almost every page load. I'd suggest doing it only once and fix all images attributes directly in the database, but the problem is too broad, I'll only outline the steps.

1. Backup the database.
2. Get all the image attachments

   ```
   $args = array(
           'post_type'       => 'attachment',
           'post_mime_type'  => 'image',
           'numberposts'     => -1
       );
   ```
3. Use the `guid` or [`wp_get_attachment_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) to get the image URL
4. Search for the URL in the database

   ```
   // $image_url = your_method_to_get_it();
   $sql_results = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare( "
           SELECT *
               FROM $wpdb->posts
           WHERE post_content 
               LIKE %s
           AND post_status = 'publish'
            " 
           ,'%' . like_escape( $image_url ) . '%'
       )
   );
   ```
5. Parse the HTML from `post_content` and `do_your_magic( $image_attributes, $post_content )`.
   [**Don't**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1287812) use RegEx, [`DomDocument`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20domdocument%20add%20image%20attribute) does the job.
6. Update the post with [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)

---

Here's a helper plugin to do this. Note that

- we can selectively trigger actions using a query parameter in the URL

  ```
  http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=updating-images&doit
  ```
- you'll have to build it step by step, **`var_dump`ing everything** until you're ready for **Step 6**

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: (SO) Updating Images */

add_action('admin_menu', 'helper_so_19816690' );

function helper_so_19816690() 
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Updating Images',
        'Updating Images',
        'add_users',
        'updating-images',
        'doit_so_19816690',
        null,
        0
    );
}

function doit_so_19816690()
{ 
    echo '<h2>Conversion</h2>';
    $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'numberposts'    => -1
        );
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );

    # Our thing
    if( isset( $_GET['doit'] ) )
    {
        var_dump( $attachments );
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 7: post your final plugin here for everyones benefit ;)